# Represent an XML Schema and its Data in a SQL Server Graph Schema

Tags: sql-server, xml, graph, sql-graph

I have a problem where I need to represent an XML Schema and its data inside of a SQL Server Database. I need to be able to access the data in a way that will allow me to create either an XML or JSON file.

I have looked at couple of solutions to this problem. First creating a traditional relational database and storing the XML data in a table representing the hierarchical structure by use of a self referencing parentId. This structure seems OK but as the size of XML is large the accessing of data is slow, as I must use a lot of recursions to obtain the hierarchical data I need. The performance of this design will tend to worsen as the amount of data increases.

Secondly, I looked at the use of creating a Graph Schema inside of SQL Server. Assigning each XML element as a node table and the xml element attributes as columns in that table. I then created a simple ‘isParentOf’ edge table, inserting this relationship between the different xml elements into the table. However, as each element is a separate node it is making queries cumbersome.

I know there isn’t a direct correlation between the XML Schema structure and Databases and have read articles on the complexity of such problems. But I wanted to reach out to the community to see if it is possible to achieve my goal using the SQL Graph Databases as this seems to be the best fit, in that I can define my elements and then create the different relationships.

I have provided some sample XML data below which contains the different permutations of the XML that I am currently working with in terms of element hierarchies, attributes, and data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document xmlns='http://mydocument.com/schema/1'>
  <BankStatement frequency='monthly'>
    <Customer>
      <AcctNo>012-3456789</AcctNo>
      <Name type="full">John Doe</Name>
      <Street>123 Street Road</Street>
      <City>London</City>
    </Customer>
    <BeginDate>18/10/2022</BeginDate>
    <EndDate>18/11/2022</EndDate>
  </BankStatement>
</Document>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First creating a traditional relational database and storing the XML data in a table representing the hierarchical structure by use of a self referencing parentId...The performance of this design will tend to worsen as the amount of data increases.

No, it likely won't. When properly architected and indexed, the search time of your tables will be `O(log(n))` because indexes use B-Tree data structures.

Let's say your table had 1 million rows in it. In the worst case scenario, `log2(1 million) = 30`. That's only 30 nodes of the B-Tree that would need to be seeked through to find your data. If your table grew to 1 billion rows, `log2(1 billion) = 40`. These are extremely small numbers for a computer to search through. (It's actually usually less than this because of something called the fan-out factor.)

Typically a recursive CTE can easily be used to efficiently crawl a hierarchical structure too. Hundreds of thousands of hierarchical rows can be crawled and related appropriately in under a second.

---

Aside from all of that, I don't even see a hierarchical relationship in your example data. Rather it appears to be a traditional data model problem that a relational structure would be well suited for.

Tables that I would recommend defining would be `Customers`, `Accounts`, maybe `Addresses` if a `Customer` can have more than one `Address`, and `BankStatements`. I'm sure your data probably has other relevant entities too.

Comment: Thanks for the comment it’s really interesting when you look at the numbers. The hierarchical structure comes from the XML. I need to store the XML Schema inside of the database as well as the data. The example is simplified but in reality the XML schema has over a thousand different elements with some elements with nested elements over 30 deep.

Comment: @Cragly No problem, data structures and B-Trees are awesome. Properly architecting a database goes a long way. I understand (at least just from the example you've provided so far) that in XML, all objects are *nested* but if you see how I derived different tables from each of those objects, it un-nests the representation of them. I don't really see a hierarchical nature (especially not a self-referencing one) when implemented as relational tables. For example, in a true self-referencing hierarchical structure, any level of child could be at any other level. E.g. a Bill Of Materials for how...

Comment: ...to build a product may be self-referencing hierarchical because `FinishedProduct` might have `PartA` and `PartB` directly below it and `PartA` may also use `PartB` below it too, to build `PartA`. A `BillOfMaterials` table that represents this relationship would hold a set of parent-child parts to represent each level of the build. But in your case, a `BankStatement` would never directly relate to an `Address`. Rather a `BankStatement` relates to an `Account` which that `Account` then relates to a `Customer`, and that `Customer` relates to an `Address`. All linear-like relationships.

Comment: Regardless, a relational database management system (RDBMS) can handle both types of data relations just fine.

Comment: Thanks J.D., but if flattered how would you rehydrate those tables  back into a hierarchical XML, JSON documents. I need to store that data somewhere. Also one thing I didn’t mention for simplicity is that data has to be verified against an XSD to as well as hierarchy I also have to consider the order of those elements, hence why I thought of Graphs as I could model the schema as nodes then the edges would be the hierarchy/order. However, it may make more sense to store the schema using Bridge Table pattern and the data referenced to this in a flatter Ed way as you described above?

Comment: @Cragly Oh sorry, it wasn't clear that you need to rehydrate it as XML again at some point after. So there's really two answers to that problem depending on why you "*need to represent an XML Schema and its data inside of a SQL Server Database*"?...if you're just storing it there to store the data and no need to query the individual objects, then you might as well just store the XML as XML files outside of the database because that's basically all they are at that point, and databases aren't meant to store files. If you insist, then you can use the `XML` or `JSON` data types and store whole...

Comment: ...documents in the database, again, only if you don't really plan to query the contents of that XML. But if you do have a purpose to store the data of the XML in the database, for querying it in different ways, then you can use the relational model I described and leave it to the application as the  consumer to rehydrate them as XML when needed. Not sure what application language you're familiar with, but this is something I've done with C# fairly easily in the past. There's frameworks for converting to / from XML (and JSON) with database entities.

Comment: @Cragly A graph database is really designed for solving graph problems (which are usually still relational in nature). An example of a graph problem is the mail delivery to a city. There are multiple different addresses (nodes) with many different streets to get to some of those addresses (edges) and there's no definitive starting or ending point for the mail delivery driver to take, since they can choose to start from any street. This is a graph of addresses and streets and can be stored properly in a graph database system. A lot of people don't realize it's literal in purpose, and try to...

Comment: ...shoehorn the wrong type of data in it. I strongly don't think a graph database would make sense for your type of data. Personally I'd go with the relational model (to have the highest flexibility and performance with querying the data) and would create a library (so it's reusable in multiple applications) in C#, using the frameworks already available, to rehydrate my XML objects when needed.